# I'm Trying to Set a Custom Icon for the Apple Watch's Force Touch Menu

Tags: swift, icons, apple-watch

Whenever I try to set an image for the Apple Watch's force touch menu, the icon comes out too big and blurry. My image is the right resolution, but still turns out weird. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

If it appears big and blurry, it *isnt* the right resolution. Consulting the HIG (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/WatchHumanInterfaceGuidelines/index.html) shows that you need 80x80 for 42mm and 70x70 for 38mm.

Answer (score 0):

Just add @2x to the image name and will work!